# Check if "value" is set in slot

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I'm moving the first steps with the Alexa app. I want to develop a simple intent that answers with a person name {personName} if a "value" was set in the slot. 
However, I am not able to understand what's wrong with the following code: as the check is enabled Alexa does not understand the request, even if the input json is correct.

I was inspired by another StackOverflow question about input validation [Alexa input validation for type AMAZON.NUMBER using dialog model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992393/alexa-input-validation-for-type-amazon-number-using-dialog-model)

```
const AnswerUserIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name ==='AnswerUserIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        var pNameObj = this.event.request.intent.slots.personName
        var testValue = pNameObj.hasOwnProperty("value");
        if (testValue) {
            var speechText = 'You entered the intent with a value!';
        }else{
            var speechText = 'You just entered the intent';
        }

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
 var name = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.personName.value;
 var testValue= (name != undefined) ? true : false;
```