# How to make multistatement request with Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa Skill and I need that when the user asks for information but it's missing the required fields for the back-end, Alexa asks the user back for this information. For example:

If the user asks `What's the temperature?` but does not give a location, Alexa asks back the location so it can be passed with the request to the back-end.

Another example is when you want to set a reminder and ask Alexa `Set a reminder`, she asks you for what and when is the reminder. I want to do the same with my skill.

[Reading the documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-object) I noticed that there's a `reprompt` and a `shouldEndSession` entry in the response Object. Is this the right way to do what I want? Or is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found an answer. There is a directive for asking the user for missing values: the [Dialog.ElicitSlot](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#directives).

Similar question: [Alexa input validation for type AMAZON.NUMBER using dialog model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992393/alexa-input-validation-for-type-amazon-number-using-dialog-model)